# Repartition multiple CSV files in PySpark into multiple CSV files

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I have multiple CSV files in S3, all of the same format, like so, each with millions of  records:

```
+----+------+------+
|ColA| Col B| Col C|
+----+------+------+
|   A|     1|     0|
|   A|     2|     0|
|   B|     3|     2|
|   B|     4|     1|
|   C|     5|     1|
+----+------+------+
```

Now I need to reformat all these files into a multiple CSVs, one for each value of ColA, like so:

```
A.csv
+----+------+------+
|ColA| Col B| Col C|
+----+------+------+
|   A|     1|     0|
|   A|     2|     0|
+----+------+------+

B.csv
+----+------+------+
|ColA| Col B| Col C|
+----+------+------+
|   B|     3|     2|
|   B|     4|     1|
+----+------+------+
```

and so on. Going through each CSV file in Spark and splitting them into individual files seems like an inefficient way to do this (I tried it, it's taking a long time). Is there a more efficient way to do this in Spark?

Comment: Have you tried using rdd? I think maybe you can convert your original dataframe into rdd, and then group by the keys in the colA, map its values and write each csv line by line?

Comment: Try `data.write.partitionBy('ColA').csv('/path')`